# Can't host nettcp and wshttp endpoints from same IIS 7 web app

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I am trying to host two endpints, Net.Tcp and wsHTTP, from the same IIS web app but counldn't seem to get it to work. When I host just a Net.Tcp endpoint, it works fine. As soon as I add the HTTP to the host, I get the following error:
"The value of this argument must be positive. Parameter name: maxAccepts Actual value was 0"

Anyone knows if this is a limitation on the IIS 7 or is something I am doing wrong? What I do is that I extend the ServiceHostFactory class and override the CreateServiceHost method. Here is the highlight of the code:

```
Public Class QLHostFactory
Inherits ServiceHostFactory

Protected Overloads Overrides Function CreateServiceHost(ByVal svcTyp As Type, ByVal baseAddresses() As Uri) As ServiceHost
    Dim QLSvcHost As ServiceHost = Nothing

    Dim ntcpUri() As Uri = Nothing
    ' I have to filter out all other uri and leave only nettcp in the 
    ' list to get it to work. But what I really want is to allow http in here too.
    For Each u As Uri In baseAddresses
        If u.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeNetTcp Then
            ReDim ntcpUri(0)
            ntcpUri(0) = u
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    QLSvcHost = New ServiceHost(svcTyp, ntcpUri)
    SetHost(QLSvcHost, svcTyp) ' <== set endpoints for each baseaddresses, etc.
    Return QLSvcHost
End Function
```

Comment: Can you try to host both endpoints without a customservicehost on IIS and if they work fine it must be with your code that is causing the problem

Comment: I have the same issue, combining two different (nettcp and wshttp) endpoint types for the same service gives me the maxAccepts error and broken pipes ...
Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2388512/389424 for http://stackoverflow.com/q/2275303/389424?